# Update postmeta after theme switch

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the postmeta table when I switch themes. I am updating the metavalue to be template-name.themename.php.

However, this only works with the default themes in wordpress.

If I go to add a new theme, and activate that, it does not work.

The metavalue updates correctly, but the new theme is overriding the custom template.

Here is the code I have.

```
    <?php
    add_action('after_switch_theme', 'update_templates');

    function update_templates() {

    global $wpdb;
    $new_template = "pl-template.". strtolower(trim(get_current_theme())) .".php";
    $pl_pages = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE pevo_page = 1");


    foreach ( $pl_pages as $pages) {

        $post_id = $pages->ID;

        $wpdb->query(  
            "
                UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
                SET meta_value = '$new_template'
                WHERE post_id = $post_id                         
            "
         );

    }
}
    ?>
```

The custom template, is just blank right now and just displays the page title

```
    <?php
    /*
     Template Name: Template Name
    */


    $the_title = get_the_title();

    echo $the_title;
   ?>
```

working code thanks to the answers, I used an array because this is within my plugin class.

```
    add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'plugin_page_templates')); 


          function plugin_page_templates() {
    global $wpdb;
    $pagename = get_the_title();
    $ispluginpage = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT plugin_page FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_title = '$pagename'");

    if ($ispluginpage == 1) {
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/plugin-template.php';
    }

    return $template;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that you have your code in the theme, probably `functions.php`. That code will only load when the theme is active, and `after_switch_theme` only runs after the theme change. There is no `before_switch_theme` that I am aware of.

You will need to have this code in a plugin or a mu-plugin file in order to have it work for all themes.

***But don't...***

This  kind of template highjacking is going to make whatever you are doing very unpopular. Not to mention that it is a very messy way to do things. You are altering database values that you are going to have to eventually clean up again.

Though it is not clear why you need to do this, or even exactly what the end result is supposed to be, I am pretty sure that they right way to do it is with the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) and/or [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hooks.

For usage examples:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+template_include
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+template_redirect

Comment: this page is unimportant and only serves as one use, also it is inside of a plugin, no themes, I will try those hooks you mentioned.

Comment: Ok. So I am sure you are doing it wrong. If this is a template required by a plugin you should be using hooks.

Comment: thanks for helping, it looks like the template_include hook is working, I was over complicating it.

Comment: yay, got it working, and I only done this for pages created by the plugin, exactly what I wanted, I updated with the working code.